# Use of signal_pending_state function to change task's state to TASK_RUNNING

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, preemption, cfs

I was going over through the main scheduling function: `__schedule()` and found a code snippet which is:

```c
if (!preempt && prev->state) {
        if (unlikely(signal_pending_state(prev->state, prev))) {
            prev->state = TASK_RUNNING;
    ...
```

Now, if a process voluntarily preempts itself by keeping itself onto the wait queue, why does the state of the process change again to `TASK_RUNNING`?

Comment: Because the process needs to handle a signal?

Comment: `man 3 sleep` ...or a signal arrives ...

Comment: That piece of code pretty much speaks for itself, doesn't it? If there's a signal to be delivered to the process, wake it up. What's not clear about it?